# Composer/Packagist could not find package for minimum stability

Tags: php, composer-php, packagist

I'm trying to install the following composer package:

```
composer require cr/hashcli
```

it is a package that I did. But when I try to install it I get the following error:

> [InvalidArgumentException]
>   Could not find package cr/hashcli at any version for your minimum-stability    (stable). Check the package spelling or your
>   minimum-stability

My composer.json is the following:

```
{
"name": "cr/hashcli",
"description": "HashCLI - PHP CLI Tool For hashing",
"type": "library",
"keywords": ["hash", "cli"],
"license": "MIT",
"require": {
    "php": ">=5.5"
},
"require-dev": {
    "phpunit/phpunit": "^5.7"
},
"bin":[
    "src/hashCLI"
],
"autoload": {
    "classmap": [
        "src/"
    ]
},
"autoload-dev": {
    "classmap": [
        "tests/"
    ]
}
}
```

Any idea on why this is happening and how can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 112, accepted):

There is no stable version of this package. Use

```
composer require cr/hashcli:dev-master
```

Edit: nowadays you might check dev-main instead of dev-master.

Comment: And what does it take to have a stable version?

Comment: Author of this package needs to release stable version.

Comment: @Bizley's answer help me! To use an unstable package you can set your `minimum-stability` to `dev` and `prefer-stable` to `true`. But if you are coding a package and you want be able to download it then, just **create a tag** using Git and your package will be found as stable on packagist then.

Comment: Neat answer. Worked for me. Too many misleading answers for this

Comment: I have created tags a while ago but still the issue. https://github.com/inimist/cakephp3-captcha. Any idea?

Comment: @ArvindK. have you followed the packagist instruction how to set up your package for the automatic updates from github? Looks like this is the case. Maybe there is no webhook added or something.

Comment: @Bizley I am not sure what was wrong. I had setup Packagist to auto sync. I created another release 1.2.2, manually updated in Packagist and it started to show 1.2.2 tag there. I did try the update last night as well but it did not work then. Not sure what was missing. Thanks anyways, it made it to install without mentioning dev-master finally.

Comment: I got this problem when trying to use a library created by a work mate. In this case I had to use "composer require myCompanyName/my-workmate-library:dev-main"

Answer (score 29):

Since you mentioned that you are the author of the package you should create a release if you think that your version may be used in production.

You can do this at GitHub:

1. Click on `0 releases`
   [image]
2. Create a new release
   [image]
3. Create a release version, perhaps `v1.0`, add a description and push the button:
   [image]
4. Try to reinstall with composer. Make sure to remove the cahce first `composer clear-cache` and then just try `composer require your/pagackge`.

---

Sidenote:

I recommend you to read [this](https://semver.org/) to understand when you should name a release `v1.0.1` or `v1.1` or `v.2.0-alpha` etc. Here is a little excerpt:

> 3. Once a versioned package has been released, the contents of that version MUST NOT be modified. Any modifications MUST be released as a
>    new version.

In other words, if you push something to your repository and you do not create another release. People are only able to download the latest release through composer.

> 

> 6.Patch version Z (x.y.Z | x > 0) MUST be incremented if only backwards compatible bug fixes are introduced. A bug fix is defined as
> an internal change that fixes incorrect behavior.

For bug fixes that are not breaking anything you may update to `v1.0.1`

> 7.Minor version Y (x.Y.z | x > 0) MUST be incremented if new, backwards compatible functionality is introduced to the public API. It
> MUST be incremented if any public API functionality is marked as
> deprecated. [...]

If you add new functionality that does not break the code you should call the next release `v1.1.0`.

> 8.Major version X (X.y.z | X > 0) MUST be incremented if any backwards incompatible changes are introduced to the public API.

If you do something that may breaks the code from other people, you may call the new release `v2.0`

> 9.A pre-release version MAY be denoted by appending a hyphen and a series of dot separated identifiers immediately following the patch
> version. Identifiers MUST comprise only ASCII alphanumerics and hyphen
> [0-9A-Za-z-].

Anything called `v1.3-alpha` or `v1.3-christmas` will be seen as a pre-release.

Comment: You saved me! Couldn't figure out how to get away from dev-master and throw up a version. Tagging is not sufficient, but doing the release worked for me (after waiting a few minutes for cache to clear up)

Answer (score 27):

If you want to be able to install dev packages you can change your composer config for that project:

```
composer config minimum-stability dev
composer config prefer-stable true
```

Comment: that fixed it for me thanks!

Answer (score 2):

For those using Packagist, Composer and GIT from the command line, just tag your package after pushing it to GitHub:

```
git push origin master
git tag v1.0.0
git push --tags
```

And provided you have already created the [GitHub Hook for Packagist](https://packagist.org/about#how-to-update-packages), Packagist will update in a few minutes and then you can run `composer require my-user/my-package` from your consuming project.