# Package development": Could not find a version of package mycomp/livesearch matching your minimum-stability (stable)

Tags: php, composer-php

I'm making a laravel composer package

The `composer.json` of the package  looks like this

```
{
    "name": "mycomp/livesearch",
    "description": "Livewire livesearch package",
    "type": "library",
    "require": {
        "livewire/livewire": "dev-master"
    },
    "license": "MIT",
    "autoload": {
        "psr-4": {
            "mycomp\\Livesearch\\": "src/"
        }
    },
    "authors": [
        {
            "name": "parallax",
            "email": "parallax4@gmail.com"
        }
    ],
    "minimum-stability": "dev",
    "prefer-stable": true
}
```

I've added it locally by adding this to my root `composer.json`

```
"repositories": [
    {
      "type": "path",
      "url": "packages/mycomp/*"
    }
  ]
```

But when I try to install the package using `composer require mycomp/livesearch`  I get:

`Could not find a version of package mycomp/livesearch matching your minimum-stability (stable). Require it with an explicit version constraint allowing its desired stability.`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Composer/Packagist could not find package for minimum stability](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41149552/composer-packagist-could-not-find-package-for-minimum-stability)

Comment: @MartinZeitler no it doesnt. thanks

Answer (score 0):

Fixed it.

Just had to add

```
"version": "1.0.0"
```

To my package's `composer.json`

Although, from what I've learnt this is a bad idea, and it's best to do version control with a VCS like Git. But for now, before I release the package and put it on github, this would suffice.